# Why hexagonal closed packed structure is not a Bravais lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, definition, crystals

Why is the hexagonal closed packed structure not a Bravais lattice?

How can one readily say that a particular lattice is Bravais lattice or not?

Comment: A Bravais lattice is a well defined concept in solid state physics, covered in many textbooks. A HCP structure is a simple hexagonal Bravais lattice with a two-atom basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definition of Bravais lattice is given by:

1.Bravais lattice is an infinite array of discrete points, appears exactly same from the point where the lattice is observed.
2. Position vector of any discrete point in the lattice can be written in the form $$\mathbf{R}=n_1 \mathbf{a_1}+ n_2 \mathbf{a_2}$$ where $\mathbf{a_1} ,\mathbf{a_2}$  are primitive, linearly independent vectors which spans the whole lattice.

Even though the hexagonal lattice follows the first definition, it doesn't follows the second one. Not all points in in the lattice can't be written as the linear combination of primitive vectors of hexagonal lattice. Thus hexagonal lattice is not Bravais.

Comment: Arn't the 2 definitions equivalent ? (Ashcroft,Mermin).So how could one hold and the other not hold?

Comment: Ref: Solid state physics, Ashcroft/Mermin,  pg 64 and 65

Answer (score 1):

Hexagonal close packed (hcp) is one of the two simple types of atomic packing with the highest density, the other being the face-centered cubic (fcc). However, unlike the fcc, it is not a Bravais lattice, as there are two nonequivalent sets of lattice points. Instead, it can be constructed from the hexagonal Bravais lattice by using a two-atom motif (the additional atom at about (1⁄3, 1⁄3, 1⁄2)) associated with each lattice point.

Answer (score 0):

In a lattice the neighborhood of all spheres or points should be identical in all directions. Based on this idea and how we make an hcp and ccp lattice by stacking closed packed 2D layers, in this video you can see how hcp is not a lattice.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zgdk-MVWY4

Comment: Makes sense, I don't see why this answer has been down voted.